# Fix 404 nginx and thin?

Tags: ruby, nginx, thin

I'm currently installing my application on a ubuntu server. and I'd like to know why, when I try to access my API, nginx returns me a 404.

I have configured thin as well as nginx but I can't find out why this doesn't work, and being new to this field I admit I don't know where to start.

i tried to change the thin config and the nginx config but nothing work yet.

thin config

```
user: www-data
group: www-data
pid: tmp/pids/thin.pid
timeout: 30
wait: 30
log: log/thin.log
max_conns: 1024
require: []
environment: production
max_persistent_conns: 512
servers: 1
threaded: true
no-epoll: true
address: 0.0.0.0
port: 3000
daemonize: true
chdir: /home/ubuntu/happer-api
tag: happer-api
```

Nginx config

```
upstream myapp {
      server 127.0.0.1:3000;
      server 127.0.0.1:3001;
      server 127.0.0.1:3002;
    }
    server {
      listen   80;
      server_name .example.com;

      access_log /home/ubuntu/happer-api/log/access.log;
      error_log  /home/ubuntu/happer-api/log/error.log;
      root     /home/ubuntu/happer-api;
      index    index.html;

      location / {
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect  off;
        try_files /system/maintenance.html $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html @ruby;
      }

      location @ruby {
        proxy_pass http://myapp;
      }
    }
```

I'm on EC2 Instance and i open the port with the amazon tool

I have also active admin on my API but i can't reach it.

Answer (score 0):

The Nginx root should end with `public` for rails project:

```
root     /home/ubuntu/happer-api/public;
```

Also can you try removing the initial dot from the domain name?

```
`server_name .example.com;`
```

And remove the other two upstream servers ending with `3001` and `3002` port. Your thin is supposed to serve only one!

Comment: thanks but same result, but i don't have access to my API or my BackAdmin. and thin log say nothing .